# Cut Off Windows RPi2 TFT

Tags: window

I am running Ubuntu Mate on my Raspberry Pi 2 on a TFT 7" 800x480 screen. For some reason, it is cutting the bottoms off of unresozable windows, such as when I need to enter wireless network info, this preventing me from finding and clicking an "ok" button. I have no option to use anything other than Marco, and the resolution is correct in the settings. Any suggestions?
Note: this does not occur in Raspian